# Scala constructor with default values

Tags: scala, constructor, null

I want to slap a read and/or write trait on the Store below. To do that I need to have default null-like values for the Schemas or functions, then check them at runtime. This is to allow a read, read+write, and write only Store. The traits will define `reader` and/or `writer` and that is all.

This would looks like:

```
//read only, exception if someone tried to write with it
val rStore = new Store[SomeType](sc, readSchema) with SomeReadTrait
//write only, this would leave inSchema as null-ish so I can check if readfrom is called.
val wStore = new Store[SomeType](sc, outSchema = writeSchema) with SomeWriteTrait
// read/write
val rwStore = new Store[SomeType](sc, readSchema, writeSchema) with SomeReadTrait with SomeWriteTrait
// another way to do read/write
val rwStore = new Store[SomeType](sc, readSchema, writeSchema) with SomeReadWriteTrait
```

But I can't figure out how to create a default null-ish value in my constructor and a default null-ish value for an internal function def.

I might be able to handle this with three abstract types, but is there a way to do something like the following to keep the code DRY. I don't care if the check is for the reader/writer function (to see if a non null-ish one was supplied by the trait) or the Schema (to see which were given non null-ish values when constructed) or both.

```
abstract class Store[T](sc: SparkContext, inSchema: Schema = ????, outSchema: Schema = ????){
  /** Reader function that reads from the location into the T and returns it, supplied by a Read trait*/
  def reader: (SparkContext, Schema, String) => T = ????
  /** Writer function, supplied in a Write trait */
  def writer: (SparkContext, Schema, String, T) => ????
  def readFrom(source: String): T = {
    if (reader != ????) reader(sc, inSchema, source) else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Store: readFrom called but there is no reader function has been defined")
  }
  def writeTo(collection: T, dest: String): Unit = {
    if (writer != ????) writer(sc, outSchema, dest, collection) else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Store: writeTo has been called but there is no writer function")
  }
}
```

Comment: I can use a default Schema value of ```inSchema: Schema = null.asInstanceOf[Schema]``` and check that in the ```readFrom``` and ```writeTo```. But still can't figure how to have a trait which _only_ defines a ```writer``` or ```reader``` function. I can create traits that define both reader and writer and throw an exception when the wrong one is called but this is a runtime error when I'd like to make it a compile time error.

Answer (score 3):

This is a weird way to accomplish what you want. If the `outSchema` is only relevant when a `WriteTrait` is mixed in, and an `inSchema` only when a `ReadTrait` is mixed in, then why are they not part of the traits but part of some other class? If you make them part of the trait, you can have the compile ensure everything is okay instead of throwing `IllegalArgumentException`s around.

```
 trait SomeReadTrait[T] {
    val inSchema: Schema
    val context: SparkContext
    def reader(sc: SparkContext, s: Schema, source: String): T = ???
    def readFrom(source: String): T = reader(context, inSchema, source)
 }

 trait SomeWriteTrait[T] {
    val outSchema: Schema
    val context: SparkContext
    def writer(sc: SparkContext, s: Schema, dest: String, collection: T) = ???
    def writeTo(collection: T, dest: String) = writer(context, outSchema, dest, collection)
 }

 trait SomeReadWriteTrait[T] extends SomeReadTrait[T] with SomeWriteTrait[T]

 class ReadStore[T](val context: SparkContext, val inSchema: Schema) extends SomeReadTrait[T]
 class WriteStore[T](val context: SparkContext, val outSchema: Schema) extends SomeWriteTrait[T]
 class ReadWriteStore[T](val context: SparkContext, val inSchema: Schema, val outSchema: Schema) extends SomeReadWriteTrait[T]
```

Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Well I'm 3 weeks into Scala and that's why I'm asking these questions :-) The reason for the Abstract class was to have a way to pass in the SparkContext at constructions time and to guarantee that the writer or reader is supplied by a trait of class or is left blank so at runtime I can check for consistency. With your method the sc is never passed in. In fact this won't compile will it? So you'd have to put the sc in each class constructor and know that by convention since there is no abstract class supply a template. More comments...

Comment: Also I need to supply a Trait that already understands the T type param, since the reader and writer will be specific to that type. -- Still the idea of putting the Schema in the trait seems like a much cleaner way to do this. And making the traits type specific is easy

Comment: @pferrel I was a bit sloppy in the answer, I corrected it so that at least the SparkContext is present. If you don't want to use generics, I think it's best if you ask a different question :)

Comment: NP, I should be able to do that much ;-) I do want to use generics because there will be many types to write. However there will be a specific implementation for every specific type. The readFrom and writeTo can be inherited if they use a generic type so the abstract class is where I went. Maybe I can do that with base generic trait that the type specific one extends. The type specific trait extends the base trait providing only ```reader``` or ```writer``` and is used to extend ReadStore/WriteStore? I'll tinker in the shell to see if that works. Traits seem right but I don't get them yet.

Answer (score 0):

With @DCKing's help I think this is what I needed. No abstract class--all traits. There is a root trait that defines the attributes and one method for readFrom or writeTo. The extended trait defines the type read or written and the reader or writer. Now to extend this we just create a new read or write trait for a specific data type, only one protected function to write. Quite DRY. Using String as a standin for various types.

```
trait RT[T]{
    val sc: String
    val inSchema: String
    protected def reader(sc: String, s: String, source: String): T
    def readFrom(source: String): T = reader(sc, inSchema, source)

}

trait StringReadTrait extends RT[String]{
    protected def reader(sc: String, s: String, source: String): String = {println("StringReadTrait#reader called, sc: "+sc+" s: "+s+" source: "+source); "StringReadTrait#reader"}
}

trait WT[T]{
    val sc: String
    val outSchema: String
    protected def writer(sc: String, s: String, dest: String, collection: String): Unit
    def writeTo(collection: String, dest: String) = writer(sc, outSchema, dest, collection)
}

trait StringWriteTrait extends WT[String]{
    protected def writer(sc: String, s: String, dest: String, collection: String) = {println("writer called, sc: "+sc+" s: "+s+" dest: "+dest+" collection: "+collection)}
}

trait StringReadWriteTrait extends StringReadTrait with StringWriteTrait

class ReadStore(val inSchema: String, val sc: String) extends StringReadTrait
class WriteStore(val outSchema: String, val sc: String) extends StringWriteTrait
class ReadWriteStore(val inSchema: String, val outSchema: String, val sc: String) extends StringReadWriteTrait
```